# What is {{.Target}} in "go list -f"

Tags: go

What is `{{.Target}}` shown in here:

> [image: here]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the code as text. Pleasew take the [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: The question was perfectly clear imho.  I was searching for an answer to exactly this question and this came up at the top of my google search results.

Answer (score 4):

`{{.Target}}` is a [template action](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Actions) that expands to the package install path.

See the [output](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages_or_modules) of  `go help list`:

> The -f flag specifies an alternate format for the list, using the
> syntax of package template.  …  The struct being passed to the template is:
>
> ```
> type Package struct {
>    …
>    Target string // install path
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in the documentation of [go list](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages_or_modules) that list packages or modules.

> The -f flag specifies an alternate format for the list, using the
> syntax of package template. The default output is equivalent to -f
> '{{.ImportPath}}'. The struct being passed to the template is:

```
type Package struct {
    Dir           string   // directory containing package sources
    ImportPath    string   // import path of package in dir
    ImportComment string   // path in import comment on package statement
    Name          string   // package name
    Doc           string   // package documentation string
    Target        string   // install path
    Shlib         string   // the shared library that contains this package (only set when -linkshared)
    Goroot        bool     // is this package in the Go root?
    Standard      bool     // is this package part of the standard Go library?
    Stale         bool     // would 'go install' do anything for this package?
    StaleReason   string   // explanation for Stale==true
    Root          string   // Go root or Go path dir containing this package
    ConflictDir   string   // this directory shadows Dir in $GOPATH
    BinaryOnly    bool     // binary-only package (no longer supported)
    ForTest       string   // package is only for use in named test
    Export        string   // file containing export data (when using -export)
    BuildID       string   // build ID of the compiled package (when using -export)
    Module        *Module  // info about package's containing module, if any (can be nil)
    Match         []string // command-line patterns matching this package
    DepOnly       bool     // package is only a dependency, not explicitly listed

    // Source files
    GoFiles         []string   // .go source files (excluding CgoFiles, TestGoFiles, XTestGoFiles)
    CgoFiles        []string   // .go source files that import "C"
    CompiledGoFiles []string   // .go files presented to compiler (when using -compiled)
    IgnoredGoFiles  []string   // .go source files ignored due to build constraints
    IgnoredOtherFiles []string // non-.go source files ignored due to build constraints
    CFiles          []string   // .c source files
    CXXFiles        []string   // .cc, .cxx and .cpp source files
    MFiles          []string   // .m source files
    HFiles          []string   // .h, .hh, .hpp and .hxx source files
    FFiles          []string   // .f, .F, .for and .f90 Fortran source files
    SFiles          []string   // .s source files
    SwigFiles       []string   // .swig files
    SwigCXXFiles    []string   // .swigcxx files
    SysoFiles       []string   // .syso object files to add to archive
    TestGoFiles     []string   // _test.go files in package
    XTestGoFiles    []string   // _test.go files outside package

    // Embedded files
    EmbedPatterns      []string // //go:embed patterns
    EmbedFiles         []string // files matched by EmbedPatterns
    TestEmbedPatterns  []string // //go:embed patterns in TestGoFiles
    TestEmbedFiles     []string // files matched by TestEmbedPatterns
    XTestEmbedPatterns []string // //go:embed patterns in XTestGoFiles
    XTestEmbedFiles    []string // files matched by XTestEmbedPatterns

    // Cgo directives
    CgoCFLAGS    []string // cgo: flags for C compiler
    CgoCPPFLAGS  []string // cgo: flags for C preprocessor
    CgoCXXFLAGS  []string // cgo: flags for C++ compiler
    CgoFFLAGS    []string // cgo: flags for Fortran compiler
    CgoLDFLAGS   []string // cgo: flags for linker
    CgoPkgConfig []string // cgo: pkg-config names

    // Dependency information
    Imports      []string          // import paths used by this package
    ImportMap    map[string]string // map from source import to ImportPath (identity entries omitted)
    Deps         []string          // all (recursively) imported dependencies
    TestImports  []string          // imports from TestGoFiles
    XTestImports []string          // imports from XTestGoFiles

    // Error information
    Incomplete bool            // this package or a dependency has an error
    Error      *PackageError   // error loading package
    DepsErrors []*PackageError // errors loading dependencies
}
```

Then :

```
go list -f {{.Target}} # print the install path of this package
go list -f {{.Root}} # print Go root or Go path dir containing this package 
...
```

You can also combine using multiple field of the structure like `{{.Name}} - {{.Target}} - {{.ImportPath}}`